# javascript - check what table is in use

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-plugins

I have got two tables, and only one javascript function associated to both. I would like to create a case differentiation in order to run different methods through an IF statement depending on which table is selected.

This is my code:

```
<table id="table1" notip="true" class="dataTable no-footer" ...>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The same for id="table2"
In the javascript side I tried the following idea, but it doesn't work:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.recalculateTabOrder = function() {
    var currentGrid = $(this);
    if (currentGrid === $('#table1')) {
      addTable_1_Item();
    } if (currentGrid === $('#table2')) {
      addTable_2_Item();
    };
  }
})(jQuery);
```

and

```
table1.recalculateTabOrder;
table2.recalculateTabOrder;
```

This is the idea.
Does anyone have an idea on how to do it, or a better idea?

Luca

Comment: At what time your logic is supposed to work : some user click or selection event or on page load itself ?

Comment: You should also add `Jquery` to the tags of this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition will always be false, two jQuery objects are never the same

```
if ( $(this) === $('#table1') ) {
```

You can compare the underlying DOM nodes

```
if ( this === $('#table1').get(0) ) {
```

or even the just the ID, or use jQuery's `is()`

```
if ( $(this).is( $('#table1') ) ) {
// or
if ( this.id === 'table1') {
```

etc

all together

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.recalculateTabOrder = function() {
        if (this.id === 'table1') addTable_1_Item();
        if (this.id === 'table2') addTable_2_Item();
    }
})(jQuery);
```